# refactor simple_form form radio-button field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a `User` model which renders a `form` patrial (using [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form)) for `new` & `edit` actions and here's the content of it:

```html
<div>
  <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :its %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <% if action_name == "edit" %>
      <%= f.input :apartment, collection: collection_of(User.apartments), as: :radio_buttons %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.input :apartment, input_html: {checked: false}, collection: collection_of(User.apartments), as: :radio_buttons %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :flat_no %>
    <%= f.input :mobile %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The radio-button field is similar for both actions but with a difference that I don't want the value in the field to be pre-selected in the `new` action. This happens because I have set the `default:` at the database level which automatically selects that value. A `checked` HTML attribute in the form checks that particular value in the menu. To uncheck it, the attribute `checked:` must be set to `false` or removed.

I want to define the radio-button field once regardless of what action it is at. If the `action_name` == `new`, it must be unchecked and checked otherwise. So, how can I refactor this field?

I have tried doing this:

```
<%= f.input :apartment, collection: collection_of(Sabeel.apartments), as: :radio_buttons, input_html: {checked: action_name == "edit"} %>
```

But this checks the wrong value of the radio button field in the `edit` form. It checks the last value in the form. This happens because all the `checked` attribute in HTML is set to value `checked` and since radio-button types can only be checked by one value, the last value is being checked. But for the `new` action the `checked` attribute is not being set hence no values are being selected by default.

Any other ideas are welcome too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do it in your controller when you create your `@user`:

```rb
def new
  @user = User.new apartment: nil
end
```